# Retornar apenas campos preenchidos no web service

Tags: web-service, rest, wcf

Fiz um REST com WCF. Em um método ele me retorna um objeto. Acontece que eu não preencho todos  os campos desse objeto e ele mostra todos no xml de resposta. Como eu faço para mostrar apenas os campos que têm valor, ou seja, os que eu preencho?

Comment: Acredito que seja a forma como ele serializa. Qual a motivação para isso? Apenas diminuir o tamanho da requisição/resposta? Caso seja isso aconselho usar JSON.

Comment: Json é o que o parceiro não quer. A programadora lá teve problemas com ele e pediu que fosse xml. A questão toda está no aprendizado e também no tamanho do xml, só isso. Como está dá pra trabalhar.

Comment: A soliução encontrada seria construir uma classe que tenha somente os atributos que serão retornados. Aí eu retorno esse objeto e pronto. A única coisa, mas não impacta, é que se houver atributos nulos, ele retornará como nil ou 0, dependendo do tipo.

Comment: Mas isso não retomaria o problema de "mostrar apenas os campos que têm valor, ou seja, os que eu preencho"?

Comment: Entendi, acontece que se o objeto tem muitos atributos e eu quero apenas alguns, essa parte eu elimino, pois não consegui resolver como eu gostaria, ou seja, mostrar tudo que é not null ou maior que zero(para Integer e Float)

Answer (score 2):

Para evitar que os campos do objeto sejam serializados no XML (ou JSON), você pode usar a propriedade `EmitDefaultValue` do atributo `[DataMember]`. Se ela tem o valor `false`, números com valor `0`, `bool` com valor `false` ou objetos com valor `null` não serão incluídos na resposta.

```
public class PT_StackOverflow_17297
{
    [DataContract(Name = "MinhaClasse", Namespace = "")]
    public class MinhaClasse
    {
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public int Valor { get; set; }

        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public bool Flag { get; set; }
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public class Service
    {
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
        public MinhaClasse Get()
        {
            var rndGen = new Random();
            var result = new MinhaClasse();
            result.Nome = rndGen.Next(2) == 0 ? "Alguma coisa" : null;
            result.Valor = rndGen.Next(2) == 0 ? 123 : 0;
            result.Flag = rndGen.Next(2) == 0;
            return result;
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        var baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        var host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        var c = new WebClient();
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c.DownloadString(baseAddress + "/Get"));
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```