# Valor quando é null não mostra o valor no xml

Tags: c#, web-service, xml, rest, wcf

Fiz isso:

```
if (lis.DT_TransacaoV == null)
                        pdv.Transacao = "Não Recebido";
                    else
                        pdv.Transacao = "Recebido";
```

Tenho no objeto `PDV` uma propriedade chamada `Transacao` do tipo string. Se for diferente de null ele faz o dever de casa, mas se vem null ele joga esse valor:

```
<Transacao i:nil="true"/>
```

Tem como inibir isso e mostrar o texto?

Web service REST com WCF.

Answer (score 1):

Tive este mesmo problema, o cliente que consumia o WS tratava o xml como string na mão, ai se perdiam quando não tinham a tag completa do xml.

A solução foi jogar um espaço em branco quando fosse nulo.

Answer (score -1):

Uma solução pode ser usando DataNotations.

```
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
```

Neste tópico tem uma resposta que exemplifica melhor só que no caso dele, ele queria que os objetos nulos não fossem serializados:  [Retornar apenas campos preenchidos no web service](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17297/retornar-apenas-campos-preenchidos-no-web-service), neste caso quando a string for nula, não vai aparecer no XML a linha:

```
<Transacao i:nil="true"/>
```

O XML aparece com a notação "i:nil="true", significa que ele esta serializando sua classe com os valores default, tente usar algo parecido com:

```
    [DataContract(Name = "MinhaClasse", Namespace = "")]
    public class MinhaClasse
    {
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public string Transacao { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Poderia detalhar melhor sua resposta?

Comment: Veja a resposta deste outro tópico: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17297/retornar-apenas-campos-preenchidos-no-web-service  Foi utilizado a solução que eu recomendei.

Comment: eu não estou dizendo que a sua resposta está incorreta, só está muito "solta". Poderia detalhar onde usar e como usar, esse tipo de coisa?